# TypeError: Result of expression 'toPage.data( "page" )' [undefined] is not an object - in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, rhomobile

I am using jQuery Mobile Split view in my application. It's working fine. 
I need split view for some pages only and for normal pages I set `data-role="page"`.
When i try to load normal pages other than split view pages I am getting the following error

```
"TypeError: Result of expression 'toPage.data( "page" )' [undefined] is not an object."
```

In `jquery.mobile-1.0.js line number 2458`

```
toPage.data( "page" )._trigger( "beforeshow", null, { prevPage: fromPage || $( "" ) } );
```

Answer (score 1):

i was facing the same issue. this doesnt happen for all pages, only a couple of them.
this not a solution but a temporary workaround.
just put a try catch around this statement :P  your app will work normally. it wont affect the working of your app. 
 tell me if u are able to find the real issue behind this error.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the try catch working fine. I know it's not a best solution. I will tell you after find a proper solution.

Comment: is this issue still coming with the latest jqm version?

Answer (score 0):

the param of changePage must be a DOM object.
So if you want to use changePage manually, you must give it a DOM object.
I suggest you use these to function to get DOM object of page

```
var allPage = $('div.ui-page');//get the DOM of the all pages on the html page
console.log(allPage);

var mainPage = allPage.prev("div#Mainpage");//find to get the previous page
console.log(mainPage);

//input for changePage must be DOM object --> so how we get DOM object?, see some previous lines we'll see the solution
$.mobile.changePage(mainPage, {transition: "slide", reverse: true}, true, true);
```

As you can see:
in the first line, I get all the DOM object from my page.
in the next line, I search in the previous DOM objects to find the page I need.
and the finally you can give it to changePage function.
It'll work perfectly.